# import Numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Numpy'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I already installed numpy. when I try to import it while appear above error message.

```
import Numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
import matplotlib.path as mplPath

# area and centroids for polygons in shapefiles
from choropie import poly_functs as sc

def get_shp_attributes(shp_file):
```

what I do?
I working on Pycharm. Please help me

Comment: Try `numpy` instead of `Numpy`

Comment: This is clearly a typo. The error message also says *"...module named 'Numpy'"* (capital "n"). None of the answers apply.

Comment: I am closing this as *"'A community-specific reason (too old to migrate)' → 'Not reproducible or was caused by a typo' ... While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."*

Answer (score 2):

If you tried `pip install numpy` try using `py -m pip install numpy` or `py -m pip install numpy --users`. Sometimes your script is referencing another python in your computer, so it thinks you never installed it.

Comment: It was [a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016098/import-numpy-as-np-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy#comment129705487_51016098) (*"Numpy"* instead of *"numpy"*).

Answer (score 1):

You may have installed it as a different name. If you would like to find out what modules you have installed type help("modules"). This will list all of the available modules you have installed. It may take a while to appear. As "soon" said, you should try importing it as: `import numpy as np` rather than `import Numpy as np`.
I hope this helps.

Comment: It was [a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016098/import-numpy-as-np-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy#comment129705487_51016098) (*"Numpy"* instead of *"numpy"*).

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is pretty much a copy of Pineda, I was having the same problem as Dulanjalee (but without the typo).

My python script worked when I ran it using PyCharm because my python interpreter for PyCharm was set to my python installation at the C:\ level. That python installation had numpy installed to it. I then tried to run the script in MS Code and it didn't work because MS Code used a different python installation. So this was my process to fix it:

I had used `pip install numpy` and that successfully downloaded numpy, but I kept getting the error because my script was using a different python installation than the one that pip was installed to. Using `py -m pip install numpy` downloaded numpy for me again, but this time in the right directory allowing my script work.